# RestAssured with duplicate query parameters

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Working on an automated test pack that uses **REST-assured** `rest-assured-3.3.0`. Have an endpoint to test that has a number of duplicate Query parameters used to drive it's search function:

```
/count?taskTypes=EAS&taskTypes=MBO&taskTypes=OTHER&taskAges=NEW&taskAges=EXISTING&ageSelection=ALL
```

**REST-assured** provides a `params(Map<String, ?> var1)` in it's request specification to pass in parameters. However this uses Map which can not contain duplicate keys. Therefore in order to construct the query in test code I am setting up the parameters and associated values in a **Multimap**:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;


Multimap<String, String> searchParams = ArrayListMultimap.create();
searchParams.put("taskTypes", "EAS");
searchParams.put("taskTypes", "MBO");
searchParams.put("taskTypes", "OTHER");
searchParams.put("taskAges", "NEW");
searchParams.put("taskAges", "EXISTING");
searchParams.put("ageSelection", "ALL");
```

The Multimap is then passed into a function to format the query and set up a GET request using REST-assured:

```
    import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
    import io.restassured.http.Method;
    import io.restassured.response.ExtractableResponse;
    import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;


    protected ExtractableResponse request(Method method, Multimap<String, ?> params, String url) 
        {
                URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
        
                for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : params.entries()) {
                    builder.addParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
                }
        
                try {
                    url = url + builder.build().toString();
                } catch(URISyntaxException e) {}
        
                return getRequestSpec()
                        .when()
                        .headers("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .request(method, url)
                        .then()
                        .spec(getResponseSpec(method))
                        .extract();
         }
```

Running this code results in a request with the following parameters:

```
/count?taskTypes=OTHER&taskAges=EXISTING&ageSelection=ALL
```

The problem is that **REST-assured** appears to remove the duplicate query parameters passed to it in the `url` parameter. Interestingly **REST-assured** offers the following interface `given().queryParam("param", 1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

Check that for loop here:

```
 URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();

    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : params.entries()) {
        builder.addParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
    }
```

looks like despite using Multimap for `params` you are still ending with Map for the builder. Here is where you got rid of duplicated keys anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I've break pointed the `return getRequestSpec()` line on which `url = count?ageSelection=ALL&taskTypes=EAS&taskTypes =MBO&taskTypes=OTHER&taskAges=NEW&taskAges=EXISTING`. So looks ok up until this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
queryParam(String var1, Collection<?> var2)
```

should work. I have used it in the past for `rest-assured-3.*`.

Example:

```java
List<String> multiQuery = new ArrayList<>(); 
multiquery.add("EAS");
multiquery.add("MBO");
queryParam("taskTypes", multiQuery);
```

Comment: Why "should this work"? Did you test this? Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Thanks, I already noted `queryParam` in the original question. Unfortunately this solution doesn't result a very reusable `request` method. It would tie the implementation to one specific use case. For this to work the `request` method would need multiple `List` parameters passed in? For e.g.

`protected ExtractableResponse request(Method method, List<String> taskTypes, List<String> taskAges, String url)`

Comment: yes. One List would have different values. This will translate to ?tasktypes=EAS&taskTypes=MB0&taskAges=NEW&takesAges=EXISTING